# ¿Como mostrar el valor de cada atributo de un objeto en cada celda de una tabla generada dinamicamente? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tabla-dinámica

Intento crear una tabla dinamicamente, donde quiero mostrar el valor de cada atributo de un objeto en una celda, y lo unico que consigo es que me muestre [object Object] en las celdas, ¿a que se debe esto? ¿como puedo conseguir que me muestre los datos?

```js
 function Socio(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password, numero) {
this.nombre = "";
this.apellido1 = "";
this.apellido2 = "";
this.dni = "";
this.localidad = "";
this.fecNacimiento = "";
this.password = "";

this.numero = function () {
    return (100 + arraySocios.lengt);
};

this.socio = function (nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password, numero) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido1 = apellido1;
    this.apellido2 = apellido2;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.localidad = localidad;
    this.fecNacimiento = fecNacimiento;
    this.password = password;
    this.numero = numero;
};

this.socio(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password, numero);
}

document.getElementById('cuerpo').innerHTML = '<input type="submit" name="mostrarSocios" id="mostrarSocios" class="opcion" value="mostrarSocios">';
            document.getElementById("mostrarSocios").addEventListener('click', mostrarSocios);

var nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password, numero;
var socio = new Socio(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password, numero);
//var socioVacio=new Socio(); 
var socio1 = new Socio('fran', 'gonzalez', 'martinez', '3533994x', '12/02/88', 'malaga', '123');
var socio2 = new Socio('pablo', 'rodriguez', 'reboredo', '8839402e', '12/02/88', 'sevilla', '123');
var socio3 = new Socio('esteban', 'pina', 'pineiro', '0299313e', '12/02/88', 'cartagena', '123');
var socio4 = new Socio('eugenio', 'martin', 'pereiro', '3500123e', '12/02/88', 'madrid', '123');
var arraySocios = [
  socio1,
  socio2,
  socio3,
  socio4
];

function mostrarSocios() {  // Obtener la referencia del elemento body
   
  var body = document.getElementById('cuerpo')   // Crea un elemento <table> y un elemento <tbody>
   
  var tabla   = document.createElement("table"); 
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");   // Crea las celdas
   
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {    // Crea las hileras de la tabla
       
    var hilera = document.createElement("tr"); 
    var titulo = ["Numero de Socio", "Nombre", "Apellidos", "Dni", "Fecha de Nacimiento", "Localidad"];   
    for (var j = 0; j < titulo.length; j++) {      // Crea un elemento <td> y un nodo de texto, haz que el nodo de
            // texto sea el contenido de <td>, ubica el elemento <td> al final
            // de la hilera de la tabla
           
      var celda = document.createElement("td");     
      var textoCelda = document.createTextNode(titulo[j]);     
      celda.appendChild(textoCelda);    
      hilera.appendChild(celda);   
    }     // agrega la hilera al final de la tabla (al final del elemento tblbody)
       
    tblBody.appendChild(hilera); 
  }
  for (var k in arraySocios) {    // Crea las hileras de la tabla
       
    var hilera = document.createElement("tr");   
    for (var l = 0; l < titulo.length; l++) {      // Crea un elemento <td> y un nodo de texto, haz que el nodo de
            // texto sea el contenido de <td>, ubica el elemento <td> al final
            // de la hilera de la tabla
           
      var celda = document.createElement("td");

           
      var textoCelda = document.createTextNode(arraySocios[k]);     
      celda.appendChild(textoCelda);    
      hilera.appendChild(celda);   
    }     // agrega la hilera al final de la tabla (al final del elemento tblbody)
       
    tblBody.appendChild(hilera); 
  }   // posiciona el <tbody> debajo del elemento <table>
   
  tabla.appendChild(tblBody);  // appends <table> into <body>
   
  body.appendChild(tabla);  // modifica el atributo "border" de la tabla y lo fija a "2";
   
  tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

```html
<html>
<header></header>

<body>
  <div id='cuerpo'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque eso es exactamente lo que estás intentando hacer, mostrar **como texto** un objeto; el comportamiento predeterminado para eso es precisamente el que has descubierto: generar una cadena con el texto `"[object Object]"`.

Lo que pretendes hacer es mostrar cada atributo de tu objeto en una columna distinta; para ello, y puesto que lo vas a usar en un bucle, lo mejor sería introducir esos datos en un *array* para poder acceder a ellos mediante un índice numérico; voy a usar una nueva función, `valor( )`:

Vamos a modificar un poco tu constructor:

```
function Socio(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password, numero) {
this.datos = [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" ];

this.numero = function () {
    return (100 + arraySocios.lengt);
};

this.valor = function( idx ) { return this.datos[idx]; }

...
```

Ahora podemos usar la nueva función `valor( )` para mostrar cada dato en su columna:

```
var textoCelda = document.createTextNode(arraySocios[k].valor( l ) );
```

Resultado:

```js
 function Socio(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password, numero) {
this.datos = [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" ];

this.numero = function () {
    return (100 + arraySocios.lengt);
};

this.valor = function( idx ) { return this.datos[idx]; }

this.socio = function (nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password, numero) {
    this.datos = [ nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, localidad, fecNacimiento, numero, password ];
};

this.socio(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password, numero);
}

document.getElementById('cuerpo').innerHTML = '<input type="submit" name="mostrarSocios" id="mostrarSocios" class="opcion" value="mostrarSocios">';
            document.getElementById("mostrarSocios").addEventListener('click', mostrarSocios);

var nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password, numero;
var socio = new Socio(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password, numero);
//var socioVacio=new Socio(); 
var socio1 = new Socio('fran', 'gonzalez', 'martinez', '3533994x', '12/02/88', 'malaga', '123');
var socio2 = new Socio('pablo', 'rodriguez', 'reboredo', '8839402e', '12/02/88', 'sevilla', '123');
var socio3 = new Socio('esteban', 'pina', 'pineiro', '0299313e', '12/02/88', 'cartagena', '123');
var socio4 = new Socio('eugenio', 'martin', 'pereiro', '3500123e', '12/02/88', 'madrid', '123');
var arraySocios = [
  socio1,
  socio2,
  socio3,
  socio4
];

function mostrarSocios() {  // Obtener la referencia del elemento body
   
  var body = document.getElementById('cuerpo')   // Crea un elemento <table> y un elemento <tbody>
   
  var tabla   = document.createElement("table"); 
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");   // Crea las celdas
   
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {    // Crea las hileras de la tabla
       
    var hilera = document.createElement("tr"); 
    var titulo = ["Numero de Socio", "Nombre", "Apellidos", "Dni", "Fecha de Nacimiento", "Localidad"];   
    for (var j = 0; j < titulo.length; j++) {      // Crea un elemento <td> y un nodo de texto, haz que el nodo de
            // texto sea el contenido de <td>, ubica el elemento <td> al final
            // de la hilera de la tabla
           
      var celda = document.createElement("td");     
      var textoCelda = document.createTextNode(titulo[j]);     
      celda.appendChild(textoCelda);    
      hilera.appendChild(celda);   
    }     // agrega la hilera al final de la tabla (al final del elemento tblbody)
       
    tblBody.appendChild(hilera); 
  }
  for (var k in arraySocios) {    // Crea las hileras de la tabla
       
    var hilera = document.createElement("tr");   
    for (var l = 0; l < titulo.length; l++) {      // Crea un elemento <td> y un nodo de texto, haz que el nodo de
            // texto sea el contenido de <td>, ubica el elemento <td> al final
            // de la hilera de la tabla
           
      var celda = document.createElement("td");

           
      var textoCelda = document.createTextNode(arraySocios[k].valor( l ) );     
      celda.appendChild(textoCelda);    
      hilera.appendChild(celda);   
    }     // agrega la hilera al final de la tabla (al final del elemento tblbody)
       
    tblBody.appendChild(hilera); 
  }   // posiciona el <tbody> debajo del elemento <table>
   
  tabla.appendChild(tblBody);  // appends <table> into <body>
   
  body.appendChild(tabla);  // modifica el atributo "border" de la tabla y lo fija a "2";
   
  tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

```html
<html>
<header></header>

<body>
  <div id='cuerpo'></div>
</body>

</html>
```